# Angular 12 warns about requested IE 11 support. Why?

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, angular12

After upgrading Angular from v.11 to v.12 I am getting the following warning:

> Warning: Support was requested for IE 11 in the project's browserslist configuration. IE 11 support is deprecated since Angular v12.
> For more information, see https://angular.io/guide/browser-support

I don't have browserlist in my project. And in `polyfill.ts` everything related to IE is commented out. Where does Angular infer this request from?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I had the same issue. It's because of the missing [browserslist](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#readme) config in your project.

If the Angular CLI compiler doesn't find a `.browserslistrc` file or a `browserslist` config in your `package.json` it will use the default config from the browserslist project.

At the moment (v 4.16.6) this is

```
> 0.5%
last 2 versions
Firefox ESR
not dead
```

which includes ie11-support.

I would recommend you to a add a `.browserslistrc`, in the root direcotry of your application (meaning in the same directory as `angular.json`) with a default config. f.e:

```
last 1 Chrome version
last 1 Firefox version
last 2 Edge major versions
last 2 Safari major versions
last 2 iOS major versions
Firefox ESR
not IE 11 # Angular supports IE 11 only as an opt-in. To opt-in, remove the 'not' prefix on this line.
```

Comment: Thank you! Interesting that the size of the build (including polyfill) didn't change

Comment: My build output size did change: main(-es5/2015).js went down by 10K (out of 1.5MB); styles.css went down by 70 bytes! :D I guess it all depends on what you're using and whether that requires polyfills/CSS transformations for IE.

Comment: I just tried this with the latest Angular CLI 16.1.4, and Angular 16.1.5. I got this error: *One or more browsers which are configured in the project's Browserslist configuration will be ignored as ES5 output is not supported by the Angular 
CLI*.
Ignored browsers: ie 11