# Angular 12 ignoring configuration files or reading from some cache?

Tags: angular, caching, build, configuration

Angular keeps warning me about IE 11:

> Warning: Support was requested for IE 11 in the project's browserslist
> configuration. IE 11 support is deprecated since Angular v12.

I came across this answer:

[Angular 12 warns about requested IE 11 support. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67646603/3319392)

I changed my .browserslistrc file as recommended, and it now looks like this:

```
last 1 Chrome version
last 1 Firefox version
last 2 Edge major versions
last 2 Safari major versions
last 2 iOS major versions
Firefox ESR
not IE 11
```

But I still get the warning.

I also have an issue with `aot` (Maximum call stack size error) so I set `aot` to false. The error disappeared. I would expect the error to reappear when setting `aot` back to true, but it didn't. Then I used another build config where `aot` is true, and the error is back.

Is Angular saving config in some kind of cache that I need to purge between builds? Because it seems that the changes I make in config files, does not always take effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### *The following answer assumes you are using npm as package manager*

1. Ensure that you dont have `browserlist` in your package.json
   `"browserslist": [ ... browser list ...]` If you have it will override definition from `.browserlistrc` file
2. Ensure that .browserlistrc is at the same folder as your package.json and where folder `node_modules` is created
3. Ensure that you clean your `dist` folder to removed before clean build

### Check the browsers your config supports

Type the following command to find out what browsers are included
`npx browserslist`

If the output of the above command indicates what browsers/versions are included

### Cache

Finally coming the cache read the [link](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#cache) here

Add/Set following environment variable (value doesn't matter, just its presence will disable cache)

`BROWSERSLIST_DISABLE_CACHE`

If you are using webpack for packaging, you can explicitly clear the cache by calling `browserslist.clearCaches()`

If above doesn't work, try deleting folder `node_modules` and `package.json` and run `npm install` to clear the cache

Comment: That did the trick... my browserslistrc was in the wrong location. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

npx browserslist showed that I had to use:
not IE 10
not IE 11
not ie_mob 10
not ie_mob 11
which got rid of the warnings