# Angular 12: Support was requested for IE 9 & IE 10 in the project's browserslist configuration

Tags: angular, browser, warnings

First, my problem is different than: [Angular 12 warns about requested IE 11 support. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67645151/angular-12-warns-about-requested-ie-11-support-why)

I'm upgrading to Angular 12 and getting this warning.

```
 Support was requested for IE 9 & IE 10 in the project's browserslist configuration. These browsers are no longer officially supported with Angular v11 and higher
```

I do have a browserlist file in the root directory. Contents:

```
# This file is used by the build system to adjust CSS and JS output to support the specified browsers below.
# For additional information regarding the format and rule options, please see:
# https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#queries

# You can see what browsers were selected by your queries by running:
#   npx browserslist


> 0.5%, last 2 Chrome versions, IE 9-11
```

In addition, my package.json references it under dependencies as:

```
 "browserslist": "^4.17.6",
```

I have also commented the import statements in polyfills.js  to support IE9, IE10 and IE11

Please suggest what can I do to get rid of that warning

Comment: do you really need IE9 and IE10 support?

Comment: remove `, IE 9-11` from browserlist file. then nothng would be transpiled to the old code

Comment: I removed , IE 9-11 from browserlist file, but the warning did not go away

Answer (score 0):

Angular 12 doesn't support IE 9 or IE 10, only IE 11: https://v12.angular.io/guide/browser-support

The last version that supports all 3 is Angular 10: https://v10.angular.io/guide/browser-support

Comment: typo ... Angular 10 supports IE9. On Angular 12 IE11 is deprecated, on Angular 13 and 14 IE isn't supported anymore.

Comment: What's the angular 12 typo?